# Part of sql server script not executing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

See my code below. Everything is executing except for the portion to create the pivot table. Instead I get the following error:

```
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@DistinctPages".
```

Here is my code. Notice that the table variable in question IS declared. What gives?

```
--Declarations
DECLARE @groupids TABLE (groupid VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @DistinctPages TABLE (pageno INT, groupid VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @groupid varchar(10)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX), @group_ids NVARCHAR(MAX), @colsNull as NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Grab groupids insert into table variable
INSERT INTO @groupids
SELECT DISTINCT groupid 
FROM wv_xmlbuild 
WHERE groupid <> 'wv_default'
--loop through pages by groupids insert results into table variable
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @groupids)
BEGIN
    SELECT @groupid = MIN(groupid) FROM @groupids
    IF @groupid = 'FIRM'
        INSERT INTO @DistinctPages (pageno, groupid)
        SELECT DISTINCT wv1.pageno, wv1.groupid
        FROM wv_xmlbuild wv1, wv_xmlbuild wv2 
        WHERE wv1.groupid = @groupid 
        AND wv2.groupid = 'wv_default' 
        AND wv1.pageno = wv2.pageno 
        AND wv1.n = wv2.n 
        AND ( wv1.x <> wv2.x or wv1.y <> wv2.y or wv1.o <> wv2.o or wv1.tb <> wv2.tb or wv1.l <> wv2.l ) 
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO @DistinctPages (pageno, groupid)
        SELECT DISTINCT wv1.pageno, wv1.groupid
        FROM wv_xmlbuild wv1, wv_xmlbuild wv2 
        WHERE wv1.groupid = @groupid 
        AND wv2.groupid = 'FIRM' 
        AND wv1.pageno = wv2.pageno 
        AND wv1.n = wv2.n 
        AND ( wv1.x <> wv2.x or wv1.y <> wv2.y or wv1.o <> wv2.o or wv1.tb <> wv2.tb or wv1.l <> wv2.l ) 

    DELETE FROM @groupids
    WHERE groupid = @groupid
END 
--create pivot table
SELECT @group_ids = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + LTRIM(groupid) 
    FROM @DistinctPages 
    ORDER BY '],[' + LTRIM(groupid)
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1,2, '') + ']'   
SELECT @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT ', coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(groupid) +', ''--'') as '+QUOTENAME(groupid)
    FROM @DistinctPages
    GROUP BY groupid
    ORDER BY groupid
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
SET @query =
'SELECT pageno, ' + @colsNull + ' FROM (SELECT pageno, groupid, flag =''X'' FROM @DistinctPages)t
PIVOT (MAX(flag) FOR groupid
IN ('+@group_ids+')) AS CustomizedPagesPerGroups'
EXECUTE (@query)
```

Comment: What happens when you use a temp table? `CREATE TABLE #DistinctPages (...`

Comment: @mrtig - It executed fine when I had a temp table. but i had to run the while loop code first and then the pivot table code. I'm trying to get away from temp table and use table variable. Thank you for looking!

Comment: @mrtig - Yes, of course :) What I'm looking for is a 2nd, 3rd, etc set of eyes on the code to help me identify where the error is.

Comment: somehow you are terminating the batch before you get to `STUFF`. I assume that's where you get the error? Also, I recommend using temp tables for performance reasons. Here's some material: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2007/01/18/11-0-temporary-tables-table-variables-and-recompiles.aspx

Comment: I cannot use temp tables for this particular client. But thank you for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use  `@DistinctPages` in `EXEC(@query)`  EXEC Uses a separate context from the calling query, which is why you are getting the object error. Consider switching to temp tables, or re define the table variable in your `@query` variable, also, if this is SQL Server 2008, you can define a custom table type, and pass `@DistinctPages` into your ad-hoc query.

Comment: That was exactly it. Took out the exec and just ran th query by itself